# PivotTable calculated field using BETA.INV not saving properly

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I am creating some PivotTables and I'm trying to add some calculated fields that use the `BETA.INV` worksheet function. I have no problem doing this and they work correctly. I can even save the documents with apparently no problem, but when I try to reopen the workbook, I get the following message:

> An item name cannot be found. Check that you've typed the name correctly and the item is present in the PivotTable report.

In order to continue opening the document, I have to accept repairs which change all PivotTables to flat text, citing "unreadable content".

What is the problem here and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem.
I spent a good chunk of time googling this, and the solution I found is that the only function that you can use in calculated fields in pivot tables is =SUM().

http://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-calculated-field.html

I resolved this issue by instead putting my BETA.INV function in a cell outside the pivot table and referencing data within the pivot table. It's not perfect but my document has stopped crashing.